# Understanding projectPoints (OpenCV C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently working on a project, in which I have a simulation environment (Gazebo based). This simulation has a virtual camera and an object, which I am tracking.

I am trying to put a bounding box around an object's image that I receive from the camera without using any CV algorithms, which is an easy task considering that I know exact position of the object in space and I can find out camera matrix, but I am failing to understand `cv::projectPoints(InputArray objectPoints, InputArray rvec, InputArray tvec, InputArray cameraMatrix, InputArray distCoeffs, OutputArray imagePoints)` function.

`InputArray objectPoints` is an array of object points that I want to project. But I fail to understand **in which coordinate system**:

- Some tutorials seems to define them in **local coordinates** of an object, which means that `rvec` and `tvec` define rotation and translation (in camera coordinates) **of the object** in space.
- In different sources, `rvec` and `tvec` stand for rotation and translation **of the camera** in the world coordinates and therefore `objectPoints` are defined in **world coordinates**.

Which approach is the right one?

Comment: You have some arbitrary points in 3D which are in a coordinate system with the origin somewhere. This rvec and tvec will be the transformation from this origin somewhere (call it local or world coordinates) to the camera. Ideally the camera will end facing the points so they can be projected in the image plane. If it is local coordinates then the origin is in the object (probably a corner or something) if it is world coordinates, the origin is in some arbitrary place (maybe even at the camera and the transformation is identity)

Comment: If I were you, I would try to find it out experimentally by inserting known values for either case and check assumed outcome. Be aware that the 3D coordinate system might not be what you expect, the y axis is pointing downwards.

Comment: Thanks, @api55. That was helpful